# Connected to an idle instance

Tags: oracle

I an facing problem while i connect to sqlplus oracle 112c. Connected to an idle instance. when i run startup command i also face 
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 2550136832 bytes
Fixed Size                  3048872 bytes
Variable Size             671091288 bytes
Database Buffers         1862270976 bytes
Redo Buffers               13725696 bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 6572
Session ID: 357 Serial number: 38301

Comment: Check error logs and post the relevant entries.  That should tell you why it won't open.

Comment: Sir i just i want to recover my DB.. i use oracle 12c . i am facing ORA-03113

Comment: Sometimes this issue happen because the archive dest is full, check it.

Answer (score 0):

As I am not yet allowed to 'comment', I am putting this as an 'answer'.

You should start by reviewing the alert log.

If you don't know where to find that, search for a file called alert_.log

Or just search for alert_*.log

Start at the end of the file, and read backwards until you see what appears to be a fatal error.

Likely there will also be a reference to a trace file.  You should also look at that.

If there is no sensitive information in those files, you could make them available and let us know where to find them.